# How do i display files from a users OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm currently working with the OneDrive API to get files from a users OneDrive.

I need to be able to display a file from OneDrive dynamically, depending on what element a user clicks on.

I Know that I can go into my OneDrive  and get a Embedded Link that I can use to display a file from my OneDrive, but this is not what I need. I attempted to use the Embedded Link combined with data binding but the link requires a authorization token unique the initial embedded link.

Essentially I want a user to click on a element corresponding to a OneDrive element (eg a `file` or `pdf`). Then have file will display in a `IFrame` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

For Office documents, you can use the `webUrl` property from a [`DiveItem`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem). This URL will open the document in the editor associated with that file type. For example, navigating to the `webUrl` for a `.ppt` file will open that document in PowerPoint Online.

For other files, the `webUrl` property simply points to the file itself. What happens when you navigate to that address will depend on the file type and what applications you have installed. Navigating to a `.pdf` generally will show that file in the browser (most browsers support PDF) but other files may not have an application and therefore just download to the local machine.

You can open the URLs into an `iframe` but be careful to ensure you're UI is taking up minimal screen area. Also make sure you're page is responsive so users can use the app in a smaller window and/or mobile device without your UI eating up so much canvas that they can't see/use the document itself.

Comment: i began doing this with the weburl but was getting problems so i now use a the microsoft.graph.downloadurl and this all works fine. Seems to embed into iframes alot easier.

Comment: For a PDF that would make sense. You'll get odd results however with different file types. I would parse the `webUrl` and see if it contains `WOPIFrame`. If it does then this document type has a built in editor and I would use `webUrl`, if not then `downloadUrl` may be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a creation of an edit link in onedrive, you can change the type of edit to embeed to get what you want, this is in php utilizing laravel, the graph api with the docs https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink

public function getEditableEmbeed($itemid){

```
    $this->refresh();
     $file = $this->getGraph()->createRequest("POST", "/me/drive/items/".$itemid."/createLink")->attachBody('{ "type": "edit", "scope": "anonymous"}')->execute();
     return $file;
}
```