# How do I embed a DriveItem from Microsoft Graph in an IFrame?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to embed a document from Office 365 in a webpage. Currently I am attempting to do this using a `DriveItem` I have retrieve through Microsoft Graph in an `iframe`.

This question was asked previously, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340136/how-do-i-display-files-from-a-users-onedrive-using-the-microsoft-graph-api/46353711#46353711?newreg=50f07a7a47b14551a2d7383266c350ca). The suggested method was to put the `webUrl` from the `DriveItem`, however when I attempt this I see the `webUrl` is returning a `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` header, and so the `iframe` is blocked from displaying it.

The alternative solution appears to be using the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`. However, when I place this in a `iframe`, the file is downloaded in my browser, not embedded.

I also investigated getting an embed-able link, [however it appears these links for `DriveItems` are only available for OneDrive personal.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink#creating-embeddable-links) I need a solution for OneDrive for Business.

Comment: I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.